# How do I get more GPM from my Delta Monitor series 13 shower faucet?

Tags: water, shower, faucet, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture

For example, is there a way to *non-destructively* modify the cartridge to increase the flow rate without damaging the cartridge and the scald guard feature?

I currently have a shower wand with the flow restrictor removed, and after having the fixture replaced following repair of some water damage behind the drywall, the new setup isn't producing as powerful a flow as before.

Comment: Is it possible it's simply clogged or partially clogged? This could happen anywhere in the line. It's not uncommon to have small debri, dust, filings, and similar clogging up aerators, flex lines, couplings, etc.  after a repair.

Comment: The flow had been nice and strong just prior to the install and still strong and consistent but noticeably less so with the new fixture. This was an upgrade to modern fixtures from the ones that originally came with my 30+ year old single-family house.

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought the old fixture was an issue. New water saving fixtures are almost always a lessened flow. I find cheaper, non-water conserving fixtures flow better.